# NUnit Sequential/Combinatorial Question

Tags: c#, nunit

I am writing some unit tests and want to make use of Sequential tag, I have found the syntax for delclaring such a test.

```
[Test, Sequential]
    public void TestCalculations(
    [Values(10000, 15000, 20000, 25000, 50000)] int salary)
    {


    }
```

How are assertions handled when doing tests like sequential/combinatorial with multiple inputs?

Best Wishes

Answer (score 8):

I haven't used these attributes myself, but I'd expect to write the actual test method body exactly as if you were writing it for a single value. Basically you'll only be presented with one value at a time, so just write the code to test that value.

Given [the documentation](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=sequential&r=2.5), I don't think `Sequential` really makes sense for your example, because you've only got one parameter. It makes sense when you've got *multiple* parameters, and basically says that the first value for one parameter should be paired with the first value for another parameter, then the second value for each etc, rather than each possible pair being executed. You might use that to give input and expected output, for example:

```
[Test, Sequential]
public void TestDivisionBy2(
    [Values(10, 25, 40)] int input,
    [Values(5, 12, 20)] int expectedOutput)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedOutput, input / 2);
}
```

Comment: Ah ok, adding an expected output array would solve my issue an allow me to assert in the normal way, thanks for the example.

Answer (score 4):

In some cases [TestCase](http://nunit.org/?p=testCase&r=2.5) attribute could be useful, it provides built in feature `Result`:

```
[TestCase(12,3, Result=4)]
[TestCase(12,2, Result=6)]
[TestCase(12,4, Result=3)]
public int DivideTest(int n, int d)
{
  return( n / d );
}
```

If you do not expect any specific result value and just want to ensure that test works fine with different input values - you can do it as well:

```
[TestCase(120000, -1)]
[TestCase(Int32.MinValue, Int32.MaxValue)]
[TestCase(-1, 23333)]
public void ShouldHandleWrongRangeValues(int n, int d)
{
     Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => { var someIntermediateValue = n * d; });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will probably end up using [TestCase] at some point too, I was just confused because the nunit documentation doesn't show you how the asserts work on some of the attributes.